# WickedPDF missing layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I have a controller like this:

```
def show
    @professor = Professor.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render :pdf => "file_name"
      end
    end
  end
```

And a simple view like this:

```
<p>Professor: <%= @professor.first_name %></p>
<p>Email: <%= @professor.email if @professor.email %></p>
```

I also have a layout 'application.html.erb';

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Myapp" %></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= yield(:head) %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <nav class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="main" role="main">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
           <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
              <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
              <%= yield %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <footer>
          </footer>
        </div>
      </div> <!--! end of .container -->
    </div>
```

When I do the following command:

```
bundle exec wkhtmltopdf 'http://local.myapp.com:3000/professors/2' - > test.pdf
```

I get a pdf with all the styles and layout properly.

However, when I go to `http://local.myapp.com:3000/professors/2.pdf` I get an error saying:

```
Missing template professors/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:pdf], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}
```

So, then I changed my controller#show action to be like this:

```
def show
    @professor = Professor.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render :pdf => "file_name",
    :template => 'professors/show.html.erb'
      end
    end
  end
```

That helps me to render the view, but unfortunatelly it doesn't render the styles and the layout.  My questions are:

1. Why do I need to specify the template?
2. Why is the layout not being rendered in the PDF?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to rename your view to show.pdf.html.erb or create a new show.pdf.erb.

The .pdf in the filename lets the handler know it can use it.

Also, you probably need to use the wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag helper to get your styles to show up. If you want to have a dual-purpose view, then something like this may be necessary:

```
<% if params[:format] && params[:format] == 'pdf' %>
  <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
<% else %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077118/image-header-on-pdf-using-wicked-pdf-and-wkhtmltopdfupdated  plz help with this query