# Rails 3, Wicked_pdf not picking up styles, print media type, or separate template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

So I've been banging my head on this all day yesterday trying to get PDF rendering to work properly. After trying Prawn and PDFKit, I found that the problem with at least getting it to work at all had to do with [wkhtmltopdf on Mac OS 10.7](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/110), but now the problem is that it completely ignores any styles I add targeting the pdf, the print media type, and any special templates.

**Here is a pastebin of where I'm at now: http://pastebin.com/LW16RYjW**

Trying all of these and several others didn't work for me:

1. http://www.snikt.net/blog/2012/04/26/wicked-pdf/
2. [WickedPDF missing layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941028/wickedpdf-missing-layout)
3. http://akabhilash.wordpress.com/2010/11/27/pdf-generation-with-wicked-pdf-in-rails/

I finally got to this setup:

- https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/87

Not knowing what else to do, I physically copied [pdf_helper.rb](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/366a0b87a8e17ee5d1f84c32141978426e9272c4/lib/pdf_helper.rb) into my lib/ directory (I don't know why it wasn't there before, or even whether it should've been upon bundling(?))

Can anyone tell me why it doesn't seem to be picking up any of the rendering options in the controller, and how I can get the styles to register without affecting the screen (html) version? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: For others that might run into this, you have to set `:print_media_type => true` as a config option when rendering. WickedPDF doesn't do this by default.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the middleware, or add the route you are trying to customize in the middleware call as documented in the README.